# Trying to save a file to SharePoint library via Powershell, but it doesnt work

Tags: 2010, powershell

Im trying to upload a file to a document library in SharePoint 2010 via powershell.  Ive followed about 5 different blog posts, most recently the one found here - http://www.sharepoint-howto.com/2012/03/14/sharepoint-2010-how-to-add-files-in-a-folder-to-a-sharepoint-library-with-powershell/

This is my powershell script, but the file just wont upload.

```
$siteurl = "http://intranet.org/IT" 
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteurl 
$docLibraryName = "Shared Documents" 
$localFolderPath = "C:\ServerStatus\Output" 
$docLibrary = $spWeb.Lists[$docLibraryName]  

$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles() | ForEach-Object { 
$fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $_.FullName)).OpenRead() 
$contents = new-object byte[] $fileStream.Length 
$fileStream.Read($contents, 0, [int]$fileStream.Length); 
$fileStream.Close(); 
write-host "Copying" $_.Name "to" $docLibrary.Title "in" $spWeb.Title "..." 
$folder = $docLibrary.RootFolder 
$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $_.Name, $contents, $true) 
$spItem = $spFile.Item  
}
```

When I run the commands individually, the variables $spFile and $spItem are empty, any idea's why these commands would fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found that the file wouldn't publish because the process that created my excel file still had a lock on it.  I had to manipulate the script to release the Excel COM object, and then the script above was able to publish the results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it ought to work, but you may want to try a more PowerShell like variant:

```
$siteurl = "http://intranet.org/IT"  
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteurl  
$docLibraryName = "Shared Documents"  
$localFolderPath = "C:\ServerStatus\Output"  
$docLibrary = $spWeb.Lists[$docLibraryName]  

$folder = $docLibrary.RootFolder  
Get-ChildItem $localFolderPath | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {  
    $contents = [Byte[]](Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Byte)
    write-host "Copying" $_.Name "to" $docLibrary.Title "in" $spWeb.Title "..."  
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $_.Name, $contents, $true)  
    $spItem = $spFile.Item   
}
```

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the answer, but I just published what the resolution was.  Appreciate the modified code though!

Answer (score 0):

If it is of any help, I wrote up some PowerShell scripts recently out of which one is to upload documents:

http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2012/10/everyday-powershell-scripts-for.html